# Recuperar tildes en c# al enviar correo

Tags: c#

Hola sucede que tengo un codigo el cual envia a un correo lo que se escibe un formulario pero al recibir el correo no muestra los acentos ni las 'ñ' correctamente, las muestra asi (y ahi deberia de decir ruben martínez nuñez):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui dejo el codigo:

```html
string sql = "SELECT nombre FROM FUsuarios WHERE Nombre = '" + Session["Nombre"] + "'";
SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
string nombre = Convert.ToString(cm.ExecuteScalar());
MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
MailAddress fromMail = new MailAddress("remitente@gmail.com");
Msg.From = fromMail;
Msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("destinatario@gmail.com"));

Msg.Subject = nombre;
Msg.Body += "PRE SOLICITUD DE FINANCIAMIENTO<br/>";
Msg.Body += "CLIENTE:" + cod.Text + " - " + nom_prod.Text + "<br/>";
Msg.Body += "STATUS: " + Status.SelectedValue;

...ETC               

Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
string sSmtpServer = "";
sSmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
SmtpClient a = new SmtpClient();
a.Host = sSmtpServer;
a.Port = 587;
a.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential
("remitentet@gmail.com", "password");
a.EnableSsl = true;
a.Send(Msg);
con.Close();             
return true;
```

Comment: intenta con esta propiedad en el correo Msg.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");

Comment: gracias! @MiguelZarate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Este problema se relaciona con el `encoding`, tienes que asignar

[MailMessage.BodyEncoding Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.mailmessage.bodyencoding?view=netframework-4.7.2)

```
Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
Msg.BodyEncoding =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```